# Can I add an external directory (or file) to IntelliJ IDEA's project view?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to know if there is a way to add existing directories to the IntelliJ project view, e.g. (in my case) a config folder located outside the project.

Comment: You may add it as new module.

Comment: According to the last respondent (who probably deleted their answer):

If I see what you mean:
You suggest copying the directory into the projects directory so that IntelliJ can see it, and adding it to .gitignore.
That's why I asked this question: to find a way if you can do this without the above things. I am thinking what if I have more projects that need the same config directory and I just don't want to copy it to every single one?